# iOS: how to fetch all objects of nested relationship parent.child.theObjectsIWant

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

For one nested relationship I would do this:

```
NSMutableArray *allClusters = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[form.clusters allObjects]];
```

But what should I do for? :

```
NSMutableArray *allQuestions = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[form.clusters.questions allObjects]];
```

Both clusters and questions are one-to-many relationships.

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're dealing with nested sets, so you probably just need to iterate through the parent sets to collect the items in the child sets:

```
NSMutableArray *allQuestions = [NSMutableArray array];

for(Cluster *cluster in form.clusters) {
    [allQuestions addObjectsFromArray:[cluster.questions allObjects]];
}
```

If this isn't what you're after, then you'll need to add some more detail to your original question.

Answer (score 2):

```
    NSSet *allQuestionsOfForm = [form valueForKeyPath:@"clusters.questions"];
```

**EDIT:**

The code above returns a nested set as glorifiedHacker said. To get a flattened set use:

```
    NSSet *allQuestionsOfForm = [form valueForKeyPath:@"clusters.@distinctUnionOfSets.questions"];
```

Comment: This approach won't work with collections. clusters is likely an instance of NSSet (or NSOrderedSet) since it responds to the "allObjects" message. Thus this approach will attempt to send the message "questions" to a collection instance, which won't understand the message.

Comment: No, the methods ´questions´ is sent to all instances of cluster, which is a NSManagedObject subclass. That's the advantage of my code..

Comment: My initial assessment that the message "questions" would be sent to clusters was incorrect (as you pointed out above). I was not tracing the keyPath correctly - thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I tested this approach in Xcode for myself and allQuestionsOfForm doesn't wind up being a flat collection, but rather a nested collection. Unless I'm mistaken, "questions" returns a collection and so does "clusters", thus yielding a nested collection. In this sense, this answer is not equivalent to my answer, and likely not what the OP was after.

Comment: Right, updated my answer. Here's more information on that: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-SW7

Comment: Thanks bijan! I learned something new today. Changing my -1 to a humble +1.